# .config() of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS. I am learning AngularJS. In this regard I found below syntax in a tutorial.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){}]);
```

Here .config() is a method. I am passing an array as parameter of this .config() method. **'$routeProvider'**  and a **anonymous function** are two elements of that array. Am I right ??

Can I make any change of the first element of the array, like **'$routeProvid'** or **'$routeProvideraa'** or **'$outeProvider'**??

Can I make any change of the second element of the array, like **function($routeProv)** or **function($routeProviraa)** or **function($outeProvi)**??

Thanks

***UPDATE***

I think I failed to express. I am updating the question

Can I use below syntax??

```
app.config(['$routeProvid',function($routeProvider){}]);
```

or

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProv){}]);
```

or

```
app.config(['$teProvider',function($routeProvi){}]);
```

Did you get this portion ??

*.config() is a method. I am passing an array as parameter to this .config() method. **'$routeProvider'**  and a **anonymous function** are two elements of that array.*

Comment: what are you trying to do? you can always changes it and see what happened

Comment: I understand the reason for this. But it is a very confusing and redundant syntax in my opinion. I think it is because of JS not having types that they needed to make it this way.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS uses the parameter name for dependency injection; once minified [the variant without the array](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation) would break.

Since strings aren't modified during minification they are used to map to their parameters. So to answer your question if you use the inline array annotation you can change the arguments to whatever you want. If you don't rename the strings or change the order of the dependencies you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The first n elements of the array are factory names and you should use something that is registered at this point. Here - router - which has its own provider (the thing that can setup the router service). The config itself hasn't got too many options to choose from as it is parsed before your app is instantinated, hence you'll use providers and constants here. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

The last element of the array is the function whose arguments should correspond to the things you pass in the array. The names here are your choice, although keep in mind the order.

So, summing up, you can't rename the thingies in the quotation marks `'$routeProvider'`, instead, know your app and what you are installing. But you can use your own names for them in the latter function($mynameforrouteprovider) but you have to keep them in order. Best if you use the same names that their author uses.

Answer (score 1):

this is the annotation in *AngularJS*...

Basically, AngularJS provides a very useful [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) system that allows to retrieve dependencies simply declaring them as function parameters...

So, if you register something through the [angular recipes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide), then, you are able to retrieve them in this way:

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .value('myValue', 'Hello World')
;

angular  
  .module('test')
  .run(function(myValue) {
    console.log(myValue);
  })
;
```

This is very useful because allows scalability, testability, ecc... but creates one problem: **It cannot be minified**

The `$injector` cannot understand the result of the minification, because function parameters are [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and the above code becomes:

`angular.module('test').run(function(a) {console.log(a);})`

So, the only way to minify angularjs code is to *[annotate](http://toddmotto.com/angular-js-dependency-injection-annotation-process/)* each **dependency that must be injected**.

Annotation can be made in two ways:

1. via `$inject` property
2. using the *array-like* annotation

Your code belong to the second case, basically, instead of passing the function directly, you can pass a javascript array that has a function in the last index position:
`[function() {}]`
the above example becomes:

```js
angular.module('test').run(['myValue', function(a) {console.log(a);}]);
```

There are many build tools that perform automatic annotation ([ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)), and is always suggested run the angularjs in [strict-di](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi) mode.

Hope it helps